# Controller function collecting SQL data in PHP

Tags: php, templates, scope

I am using a MVC framework, based on PHP

In my controller, I have the following functions :

```
public function listing($tag=null, $page=1)
{
    $this->posts('`online`=1', $tag, $page, '%s/%d/');
    $this->locations('`parent`=1');
}
```

In the same file, I have 2 functions that collect datas from 2 MySQL tables, one for the locations :

```
private function locations($query)
{   
    // Collect Locations
    $locations = new Locations('WHERE '.$query.' ORDER BY `name` ASC');
    $total_locations = $locations->count();

    // Template
    require Template::render('Posts', 'listing.html');
}
```

and another one for the posts :

```
private function posts($query, $tag, $page)
{
    // Collect Posts
    $posts = new Post('WHERE '.$query.' ORDER BY `date` DESC');
    $total_posts = $posts->count();
    $pages = ceil($total_posts/24);

        if($page < 1) $page = 1;
        if($page > $pages) $page = $pages;

        $min = $page - 4;
        $max = $page + 4;

        if($min < 1)
        {
            $max += 1 - $min;
            $min = 1;
        }

        if($max > $pages)
        {
            $min += $pages - $max;          
            if($min < 1) $min = 1;          
            $max = $pages;
        }

        $posts->query('LIMIT '.($page*24-24).',24');


    // Template
    require Template::render('Posts', 'listing.html');
}
```

In the public function (listing), when the first line is `$this->posts...` , it correctly display the Posts but doesn't display the Locations (it just display "Array".

If I put `$this->locations...` first, then it displays correctly the Loctions but not the Posts.

I don't show you more of the code since I believe it comes from a writting mistake in my `listing function`

How can I display both of the arrays ?

On my view page, I display locations/posts like that :

```
<?php while($location = $locations->fetch($i)): ?>
    <p>
         <?php echo $location->title; ?>
    </p>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by merging the 2 `private functions together` and just removing `$this->locations('`parent`=1');` from the `public function`

The design was called 2 times, once with the locations and another time with the posts, since I called the template page 2 times.

The solution was simply to merge the 2 functions together !

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is here

```
require Template::render('Posts', 'listing.html');
```

I don't now what these parameters means but my guess is that first one is name of variable in template and for both of them You set it as Posts.

Comment: Nice catch but actually the first parameter is the name of the folder `my_path/Posts/listing.html`
So they are both the same since I want the 2 arrays to display on the same page

Comment: There's nothing else in this file except the `<?php
class Ads extends Controller
{` at the beginning

Comment: data comes correctly but actually the design is showed twice on the same page : once with the locations and no posts, and a second time with no locations but with the posts displayed.

Comment: Because You are rendering it twice from different methods and locations and posts are local variables. Move them to $this->post and $this->locations and call template from listing.

Comment: Yes the templating was called 2 times !
It's solved now, thanks for the help !